Set-PnPTaxonomyFieldValue gives 'cannot bind parameter' error
I am using PnP.Powershell version 2.12.0.
I am trying to set values of two new managed metadata columns in a list using values from other columns. But I keep getting the following error:

Cannot bind parameter 'ListItem'. Cannot convert the "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[System.String,System.Object]" value of type | "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Object,
| System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]" to type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem".

First I get the list item and the relevant fields as follows:
$colItems = (Get-PnPListItem -List $oList -id 236 -Fields “Orig Field 1”, “Orig Field 2”, “New Field 1”, “New Field 2”).FieldValues

This is technically a collection, so I used a forEach loop to get $oItem. All the columns are managed metadata fields.
Then I tried two approaches to setting "New Field 1"
Set-PnPTaxonomyFieldValue -ListItem $oItem -InternalFieldName 'New Field 1' -TermID "ID String"

Where "ID String" is actually the GUID for the term, and
Set-PnPTaxonomyFieldValue -ListItem $oItem -InternalFieldName 'DEDiscipline' -TermPath = $NewValue

Where $NewValue is in the form "Term Group|Term Set|Term"
Nothing works, and I keep getting the error above. I have gone into Entra ID admin and added additional permissions in Microsoft Graph and SharePoint, so I have Sites.FullControl.All in both.
I have also tried using just Set-PnPListItem as follows:
Set-PnPListItem -List $oList -Identity $oItem -Values @{"New Field 1"=$NewValue}

I've pasted my API permissions below:

I use the following syntax for connecting:
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -ClientId <clientID> -Tenant <Domain>.onmicrosoft.com -Interactive


Would you like to copy data from column1 to column2 in the same list for the items?

I am trying to use the value of old column 1 to set the value of new column 1 and old column 2 to set new value 2. It's not exactly a copy, because they're different but similar term sets. I'm migrating from the sandbox solution to a permanent solution.

Can you show a screenshot of all your api permissions of your app?

@Danny, I added the screenshot.

How do you use Connect-PnPonline?

@Danny, posted the syntax I use. I have no problem with other pnp.powershell commands, but this one is giving me problems.

Is the taxonomy field a multi value or single value?

@Danny, it's a single value field.

Can you accept the answer so others will know it worked?

I can reproduce your error.
When u use:
$colItems = (Get-PnPListItem -List $oList -id 236 -Fields “Orig Field 1”, “Orig Field 2”, “New Field 1”, “New Field 2”).FieldValues

You don't get a ListItem object but a collection of field values. You should remove .FieldValues so you get a ListItem oject.
So try:
$listItem = (Get-PnPListItem -List $oList -id 236 -Fields “Orig Field 1”, “Orig Field 2”, “New Field 1”, “New Field 2”)
Set-PnPTaxonomyFieldValue -ListItem $listItem -InternalFieldName 'New Field 1' -TermID "ID String"

comment by TS
Thanks! I tried that and it worked. I still need to access the list of fields, to pull some values, but now I do it using the following:
$NewValue = $PathPrefix + $ListItem.FieldValues.OrigField1.Label

@Danny, I appreciate the help!
